# Select boxes not keeping selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select, drop-down-menu

So, I'm new to development and I'm having some problems with a script. In practice, I have interconnected drop-down menus, which will filter the data on the display. The first country menu is what makes all the others click.

The script sends an HTTP GET request to a PHP script with a country code parameter and retrieves the data in JSON format. Then, populate the select element "distributorChange2", so are all the others to follow.

The fact is that when I press the button that will make the filter, the selections that I have selected in the various menus do not remain, that is, they return to choose, except for the country that the first box.
What would be the reason?

```
<script src="../assets/js/intro.js"></script>
<script>
function startTour() {
  var tour = introJs(); // WP
  tour.setOption('showProgress', true);
  tour.setOption('tooltipPosition', 'auto');
  tour.setOption('positionPrecedence', ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']); // WP
  tour.start(); // WP
}

if ($('[data-intro]').length > 0) {
  $('#helpDiv').show();
}

$('.countryChange').on('change', function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  var url;

  let dropdown = $('select[class=repsChange]');
  dropdown.empty();
  //dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>- Choose</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  url = '../Communs/repsCountry.php?country=' + code;
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', key).text(entry));
    }); //WP
  });
});

$('.repsChange').on('change', function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  var url;

  //Resume 
  let dropdown = $('select[class=distributorChange]');
  dropdown.empty();
  //dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>- Choose</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  url = '../Communs/distributorReps.php?reps=' + code;
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', key).text(entry));
    }); //WP
  });
});

$('.distributorChange').on('change', function() {
  var code = $(this).val();
  var url;

  //Resume
  let dropdown = $('select[class=productChange]');
  dropdown.empty();
  //dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>- Choose</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  url = '../Communs/productsDistributor.php?distributor=' + code;
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', key).text(entry));
    }); //WP
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `dropdown.empty()` removes all the options from the dropdown, and it no longer remembers which one was selected.

Comment: Does it even make sense to remember what option was selected, if you're replacing the options?

Comment: You could save the value before reloading the menu, then assign it after.

Comment: But if it doesn't empty my combo how does it do? Wouldn't we be adding values all the time? From what I've seen, I can't remove dropdown.empty();

Comment: Yes. You need to empty it if you're going to completely replace the contents. And if you're replacing it with unrelated options, why should it keep the old selection?

Comment: If the menu contains `A, B, C` and `C` is selected, then you replace it with `D, E, F`, what should the selection option be?

Comment: The menu contains A, B, C, D interconnected with each other, when I choose A, B clicks me, B clicks me C and etc. For orientation reasons, i.e. having the filter I made visible after pressing the filter button, so I would like the chosen options to remain set to select, and if I wanted to make the filter again, it would be enough to go to To change option, or set a choose that B, C, and D would return to empty, that is, they will return to choose.

Comment: Cascading menus are usually used when the options change. For instance, menu 1 is countries, menu 2 is states, menu 3 is cities. When you change the country, you get a completely different set of states. If the options aren't changing, you shouldn't be reloading the menus at all.

Comment: Problem solved! The values reset when I applied the filter because I was passing it the wrong variables: In B (REPS) I was passing variable B, which had to go to C, because C needs to know what's in B to activate. And in B went A(COUNTRY).

<form method='post' action='./?reload'>
<div..>
<?php createSelect($countryList, 'country_name', _('Country'), ' ', 'countryChange2', 'country_name', $country_name, ' ');?>
</div>

<div..>
<?php createSelect($DAO->getCountryRepsList($country_name), 'reps_country', _('Reps'), '', 'repsChange', 'option_reps', $option_reps, ' ');?>
</div>
..
</form>

Comment: Post the solution as an answer below.